# basic combinatorics question(cells and balls)

Tags: combinatorics

How many possibilties are there to split **K** Unique balls to **N** Unique Cells, if the order in the cells matters and there needs to be the same number of balls in each cell?

I would like an explanation on the way of thinking, I know the formulas..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the balls inside the cells matters, the counting is simple: each permutation of the $K$ balls corresponds one-to-one to a desired distribution. Hence the number is $K!$

A more complicated way: Let $M=K/N$ be the number of balls per cell. The balls to go in the first cell can be selected in ${K \choose M}$ ways ; but, as order inside the cell matters, we must multiply that by $M!$, which gives $\frac{K!}{(K-M)!}$ For the second, we get ${K-M\choose M} M!= \frac{(K-M)!}{(K-2M)!}$ ways... etc

Hence the number of ways is

$$ \frac{K!}{(K-M)!}\frac{(K-M)!}{(K-2M)!}\cdots \frac{(2M)!}{(M)!} M!=K!$$